# Laravel small standalone one-off script without artisan command?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to check something small in Laravel, so I just want to make a small script to check it.

I know that I can do it with

```
php artisan make:console ...
```

But It will add a file to the App/Console/Command, and I will need to update app/Console/Kernel.php. It means that I will have do commit it to source control, which is really not needed.

Is there a way to have a **standalone** laravel script which will give me access to the Laravel Components?

I am using Laravel 5.2, (make:command doesn't exists, only make:console)

Just an example for what I tried:

```
<?php

use App\User;
use DB;

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__.'/..//bootstrap/app.php';

echo "hello world\n";
$res=User::where('id',5)->first();
echo "end!\n";
?>
```

But I am getting an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connection() on null in /var/www/html/dpriceit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:3314
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/dpriceit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(3280): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveConnection(NULL)
#1 /var/www/html/dpriceit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1880): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getConnection()
#2 /var/www/html/dpriceit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1853): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newBaseQueryBuilder()
#3 /var/www/html/dpriceit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1823): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQueryWithoutScopes()
#4 /var/www/html/dpriceit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(3524): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQuery()
```

### UPDATE

I tried creating a console command

```
php artisan make:console MyTempTest
```

But when I do `php artisan list` I don't see its signature in the list of available commands.

Comment: `php artisan tinker` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#tinker

Comment: `make:console` doesn't exist, you probably meant `make:command`. And no need to update `app/Console/Kernel.php`.

Comment: Would be great to know what the `something small` is

Comment: tinker is interesting, but I need to run a longer script (few lines of code). I tried to do make:command, but if not updating Kernel.php, it says that command is not defined

Comment: "something small" = few lines of code @CaddyDZ

Comment: Would be great to know what the `few lines of code` are

Comment: I updated the question @CaddyDZ

Comment: In newer laravel you don't need to update Kernel.php because it loads dynamically every file in Commands folder, in laravel 5.2 you have to load them manually. Tinker is super good for testing purpose

Comment: Oh... I agree, I have seen it mentioned somewhere. It is a production server, can't upgrade to 5.8 now. Tinker is nice, but running from file is better for me (can save the file for future reference, debugging, making updates, etc). Any idea if it is possible in Laravel 5.2?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a console-based solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix the error you're getting, boot up the application's kernel and handle the response like so

`app\script.php`

```php
<?php

use App\User;

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

echo "hello world\n";
$res = User::find(5)->name;
var_dump($res);
echo "end!\n";
```

Then from a terminal, run `php app/script.php`
Result:

```
$ php app/script.php 
hello world
string(11) "John Doe"
end!
```

Answer (score 0):

When I want to try/test something in Laravel, I usually do one of three things:

If the "something" I want to try is a simple one-liner I use Tinker: `artisan tinker`. This gives you the fully booted Laravel Framework, ready to use any class or function you want. This is usually my go-to when I want to: Test a global helper function I just created; Create a model using a factory, to check if my factory is setup correctly; Check if my $casts array on a model is setup the right way;

---

Another scenario might involve a bit more code, maybe a few lines to retrieve some data from the database, mutate it and show it on a page. For this you can simply create a closure based route in the file `routes/web.php`:

```php
Route::get('test-url', function () {
    $user = User::where('email', 'user@example.com')->first();

    $user->makeAdmin()->save();


    // I can see on the page if the attributes have been changed, as a result of the makeAdmin() call.
    return $user->getAttributes();
});
```

The same is possible for console routes. Add a structure like this in your `routes/console.php` file:

```php
Artisan::command('test:functionality', function () {
    $instance = new BusinessLogic();

    $result = $instance->someVeryInterestingMethod();

    dump($result);
});
```

You can then call this function from the command line with `php artisan test:functionality`. You can, of course, call the command whatever you like.

---

Then the last scenario; when I want to try something new (like a new package, library, plugin) and it will be more than a few lines of code. I create a new test class with `php artisan make:test ThrowawayTest` (or another randomly chosen name). I can then add a few lines of code and run it with PHPUnit. I have set my editor to launch the test that my cursor is on with the key-combination `CTRL-T` so that I can re-run it quickly when some code changed.

This means I can let some code stay in its function, and write a new function to elaborate on the things I just learned about the new package. When I am finished I can either leave the code and commit it to the repository, so that I can check the code later on when I need to use some of it again for production code. I can also throw away the test file if it seems like I won't need the code for reference in the future.

This last solution also gives me the added benefit of being able to use assert statements from PHPUnit.

---

Hope this gives you some insight on the different possibilities with the Laravel Framework when it comes to trying or testing out new stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the very through answer. The route is a nice idea, but I think it means that it will be accessible from the internet, which is a risk. The phpunit is also a good idea, but as this is the production server, I prefer a solution without phpunit (if possible).

Comment: Thanks. The console approach works for Laravel 5.8. (It works for 5.2 too, except that 5.2 also needs to register the command in Kernel.php, which I wanted to avoid). Check the solution that I accepted it works for 5.2 as well.

Comment: Too bad your production installation isn't updated to the latest version, my solution does not work then. I do want to warn you that the answer you accepted is a very VERY bad practice. You do not have the proper exception handling in place like you would when going the extra mile by creating a command class. This is especially troublesome since you are planning to do this in a production environment...

Comment: I will take that into account, thanks for the warning. However for my current purpose it is good enough, and in the future I will try to upgrade to 5.8 and use the command class like you suggested